# knockout.js 'ko' dissapears from page in event handler on Android Browser 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-events, android-browser

I am observing very peculiar behaviour, when testing system on Samsung tablet some of links stopped working. To make it easier to debug I am using Chrome Developer tools emulator, when page is loaded I can call kncoukout.js global `ko` from console for debugging (like getting context for bound elements...) thing is when I am trying to debug from event handler `ko` vanishes.
Have a look at screenshot below.
[image]

I have been able to access `ko` when not in callback,
then I placed breakpoint in event handler and tried to access `ko` again on `a` `click` and it's not there anymore, and then it fails with error of `ko` not being there.
**What is going on, how can `ko` just disappear?**

Not that I think it matters (same happens in any event handler), but someone will ask for code that makes `ko` disappear.

```
 var parseHrefBinding = function (link) {
        var newHref = null;
        var boundEl = $(link).closest('[data-bind]')[0];
        if (boundEl) {
            var data = ko.dataFor(boundEl);
            if (data) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('data-bind', link.attributes['data-bind'].value);
                ko.applyBindings(data, a);
                newHref = a.href;
            }
        }

        return newHref;
    };

    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        var res = true;
        var link = this;
        var parent = $(link).parents('a')[0];
        if (parent) {
            // The default Android browser (V2-4.1) sets nested a[href] to their parent's href.
            var href = parent.href === link.href ? parseHrefBinding(link) : link.href;
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.location.href = href;
            }, 10);
            res = false;
        }

        return res;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God this is epic, it turns out that to use globals in event handlers on `Android Browser 4` one has to add `window` in front of `ko` eg. `window.ko` see screenshot below.

[image]

so fix was as simple as changing

`var data = ko.dataFor(boundEl);`
to
  `var data = window.ko.dataFor(boundEl);`